# Proving the Product Topology does define a topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X, Y$ be topological spaces and define the product topology on $X \times Y$ to be given by $U \subseteq X \times Y$ is open if for all $(x,y) \in U$ there is some open neighbourhood of $x$ in $ V_x \subseteq X$ and some open neighbourhood of $y$ $V_y \subseteq Y$ such that $V_x \times V_y \subseteq U$.

It is not clear to me that this actually defines a topology, and I want a proof that follows directly from the definition of a topology.

I know that in order to show this is the case I must show that the empty set is open, the whole set is open, the intersection of two open sets is open, and that any union of open sets is open.

The first three are clear to me - for the third, I can do this by for any $(x,y) \in U_1 \cap U_2$ taking the intersection of the product of the open neighbourhoods $V_x^1 \times V_y^1 \cap V_x^2 \times V_y^2$ which must lie inside $U_1 \cap U_2$.

How do I prove that any union of open sets is open in this topology?

Comment: If $(x,y) \in \bigcup_{\alpha} U_{\alpha}$, choose an $\alpha_0$ such that $(x,y) \in U_{\alpha_0}$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is the product topology a topology?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479178/how-is-the-product-topology-a-topology)

Comment: @SaeidAli This is not a duplicate; at least not of the question you've linked. In that question the asker erroneously takes the open sets of $X \times Y$ to always be of the form $U_1 \times U_2$ and then, obviously, gets stuck. Also, the answer there does not at all address this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a collection of open sets in $X \times Y$ and say $U = \bigcup_{i \in I} U_i$. You want to prove that $U$ is open as well.

Take $(x,y) \in U$. Then, by definition of $U$, there is an $i \in I$ such that $(x,y) \in U_i$. Because $U_i$ is open, there is an open neighborhood $V_x$ of $x$ in $X$ and an open neighborhood $V_y$ of $y$ in $Y$ such that $V_x \times V_y \subseteq U_i$. Then also $V_x \times V_y \subseteq U$.

Therefore $U$ is open.

Comment: What abou the intersection?

Comment: @GabrielB.H.Lisboa The OP has given the argument for the intersection in the question itself already.